# Firebase storage.object().onChange is now deprecated,

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

Im doing a trigger to resize image after upload to firebase database but I got this message: Error: "onChange" is now deprecated, please use "onArchive", "onDelete", "onFinalize", or "onMetadataUpdate".
    at ObjectBuilder.onChange (/home/kill/trigger/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/storage.js:88:15), I aslso tried : functions.storage.object().onArchive, it`s works on terminal but when i check in the function on firebase GUI, there is a error code:13, "failed to configure trigger..", someone could help me? Appreciate guys

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
 // // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.onFileChange = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
    console.log(event);
    return;
});
```

Comment: The message is telling you that onChange is deprecated and you should be using one of the other storage trigger types instead.  You probably want onFinalize.  Please read the documentation for storage events.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events

Answer (score 7):

You have to use onFinalize() instead of onChange()